# Fluent / Expressive Builder Unit Test and IOC

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have to admit to being slightly confused with a practical application to a textbook lesson.

Reading this article [here](http://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2013/07/15/flexible-and-expressive-unit-tests-with-the-builder-pattern/) and watching Mark Seeman's video on Pluralsight I understand using the builder pattern to separate construction from representation.

For example this:

```
public class Employee
{
   public Employee(int id, string firstname, string lastname, DateTime birthdate, string street)
   {
    ....do stuff..
   }
}
```

A typical unit test would have repetitive and extra information in the "arrange" section:

```
public class EmployeeTest
{
   [Test]
   public void Test1()
   { 
     // Arrange
     Employee emp = new Employee(1, "Joe", "Blow", new DateTime(1970, 1, 1), "Somewhere");
    }

   [Test]
   public void Test2()
   { 
     // Arrange
     Employee emp = new Employee(1, "Joe", "Blow", new DateTime(1970, 1, 1), "Somewhere");
    }

   [Test]
   public void Test3()
   { 
     // Arrange
     Employee emp = new Employee(1, "Joe", "Blow", new DateTime(1970, 1, 1), "Somewhere");
    }
 }
```

Using Fluent/Expressive we would have a builder for the arrange and thus our test would instead be

```
public class EmployeeTest
{

   [Test]
   public void GetFullNameReturnsCombination()
   { 
      // Arrange
      Employee emp = new EmployeeBuilder().WithFirstName("Joe").WithLastName("Blow");
   }
}
```

---

> Now how does that apply to my world?

In the real application we are using Ninject for IOC but I am not sure how I would use it in conjunction with builder pattern.

say my constructor was this:

```
public Employee(IDepartment _department, IFacility _facility)
```

In the unit test builder pattern implementation would my "build" be hooked/registered to Ninject the same as always?

```
public class EmployeeBuilder
{

  public Employee Build()
  {
    return new Employee(IDepartment _department, IFacility _facility);
  }

}
```

or would I perhaps use a MOQ in EmployeeBuiler.Build? After all the idea of a unit test is that it would be able to operate on just a single "unit" and not have to spin up the entire SUT?

So to be clear the question is how do I create unit test with the builder pattern for IOC and or how does Moq fit in...or is Moq similar to fluent builder pattern only using Lambda's instead?

Comment: I'm sorry down voter...clearly I am confused. It wasn't my desire to ask a bad question.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the downvote either. The question is a bit long-winded, but not unreasonable.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think you shouldn't use NInject in your unit tests.
In my opinion using builder pattern the unit test would look like : (Using pseudo-mocks)

```
public class EmployeeBuilder
{
    IFacility facility;
    IDepartment department;        

    public Employee Build()
    {
         return new Employee(IDepartment _department, IFacility _facility);
    }

    public EmployeeBuilder WithDepartment(IDepartment _department)
    {
        this.department = department;
        return this;
    }
    public EmployeeBuilder WithFacility(IFacility _facility)
    {
        this.facility = facility;
        return this;
    }

    public static implicit operator Employee(EmployeeBuilder instance)
    {
        return instance.Build();
    }
}
[TestFixture]
public class Tests
{
    [Test]
    public void Test1()
    {
        IFacility facility= MOCK(IFacility);
        IDepartment department= MOCK(IDepartment);
        Employee employee = new EmployeeBuilder().WithFacility(facility).WithDepartment(department);

        [exercise]

        [asserts]
    }
}
```

Hope I helped